# Gtting unterminated string literal error in OpenCart Page template

Tags: javascript, opencart

I am getting unterminated string literal error.

```
content:  '<div><p>
```

Here is my code written in *.tpl file. The code is written in document ready function.

```
content:  '<div><?php echo strlen($gmap['onelinetext'])>0 ? $gmap['onelinetext'] : $gmap['maptext']; ?></div>'
```

When i update content from back end for example "14534 Mayfair Dr" It populate error.

Can some one guide mein how can i fixed this error.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

From the information you supplied I would assume that the PHP echo is inserting a string containing newline characters. One possible solution would be to escape the newline or replace them '
' in the PHP code.

The function you need is str_replace. The following is taken form the PHP manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
<?php
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: It still not working. I used the following code [code]content:  "<div><?php echo strlen($gmap['onelinetext'])>0 ? stripslashes($gmap['onelinetext']) : stripslashes($gmap['maptext']);?></div>"[/code]

Comment: stripslashes does not do what I recommended. You need str_replace, I have added a reference to the PHP str_replace documentation